# Trouble reading data from .dat file obtained from an SDR

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, signal-processing, spyder

I am trying to read data in Python for some signal processing. The data I have obtained from a SDR is stored as .dat

```
with open('test.dat', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
hackrf_data = f.read()
```

The error I am getting at the moment says "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 3: invalid continuation byte" and I am unsure how to solve this.

I would like to store the data from the file into 2 arrays

```
I[] and Q[]
```

as I am working with I/Q samples and then plot time time-domain and f-domain representations.

At the moment, I am struggling to solve the error I am getting. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try ignoring the errors in encoding,

```
with open('test.dat', 'r', encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
    hackrf_data = f.read()
```

Of course, it would be better if you can find the true encoding of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The file encoding is uint8 alternating I & Q samples, not utf8.

Answer (score 0):

if you use numpy it is very simple:

```
import numpy
f = numpy.fromfile(open("filename"), dtype=numpy.uint8)
```

The parameter dtype changes according to the input of the File_Sink block.
Some examples are: numpy.int16, numpy.int32, numpy.float32, numpy.complex64

GNU Radio Website - File Sink: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/File_Sink

To convert the file into csv:

```
numpy.savetxt('filename.csv', f, delimiter=',')
```